# Getting error in vertica:For 'IN', types varchar and int are inconsistent DETAIL: Columns: unknown and unknown

Tags: vertica

I am trying to execute below query in vertica:

```
select case 
when to_char(to_date('02-15-2017','mm-dd-yyyy'),'mm')in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) then 
(select to_char(add_months(trunc(to_date('02-15-2017','mm-dd-yyyy'),'year'),-2),'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual);
else 
(select to_char(add_months(trunc(to_date('02-15-2017','mm-dd-yyyy'),'year'),10),'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual)
end ett from dual;
```

Query is getting expected results in oracle but in Vertica Getting error

> :For 'IN', types varchar and int are inconsistent DETAIL: Columns:
>   unknown and unknown.

Expected Result is fiscal Start date as 1st Nov 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The base problem is that you are comparing a string to a number in your IN() predicate. (`TO_CHAR()` with a list of numbers). While Oracle (which your used syntax suggests) often implicitly converts data types to make a comparison happen, Vertica, like most other more ANSI compliant databases, is much stricter.

And you could have written your statement in a more concise way:

- You don't need the `FROM dual` clause in Vertica (even if it implicitly adds it internally)
- You wouldn't even have to nest the SELECTS in Oracle; it's enough to SELECT the whole CASE expression.
- You could formulate the date literals much easier, by using the ISO format and preceding that string with the DATE keyword.

So, in general, I'd have written it like so:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(DATE '2017-02-15') <= 10
     THEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2017-02-05','YEAR'), -2),'mm-dd-yyyy')
    ELSE  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2017-02-05','YEAR'), 10),'mm-dd-yyyy')
  END AS ett
;
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot marcothesane. this query helped.